# Can't read csv data from gzip-compressed file which stores name of archived file with Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to read csv data from gzip archive file which also stores name of the archived data file. The problem is that pandas.read_csv() picks the name of the archived file and returns it as very first data entry in returned DataFrame. How can I skip the name of the archived file? I looked at all available options of pandas.read_csv() and could not find the one that would allow me to do it.

Here is how I create my gzip archive file in python:

```
import pandas as pn
import numpy as np
import tarfile

a = np.ones((10, 8))
np.savetxt('ones.dat', a)
fh = tarfile.open('ones.tar.gz', 'w:gz')
fh.add('ones.dat', arcname='numpy_ones.dat')
fh.close()

f = pn.read_csv('ones.tar.gz', compression='gzip', sep='\s+',  header=None)
In [32]: f
Out[32]: 
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
0            numpy_ones.dat   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
2  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
3  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
4  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
5  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
6  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
7  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
8  1.000000000000000000e+00   1   1   1   1   1   1   1 NaN
9                       NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I am using Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03).
Numpy: '1.9.2'
Pandas: '0.16.2'

Many thanks,
Masha

Answer (score 2):

Use tarfile again:

```
fh = tarfile.open('ones.tar.gz', 'r:gz')
f = fh.extractfile('numpy_ones.dat')
df = pd.read_csv(f, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm :)