# Read .tar.gz file in Python

Tags: python, file, tar, gzip

I have a text file of 25GB. so i compressed it to tar.gz and it became 450 MB. now i want to read that file from python and process the text data.for this i referred [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018512/reading-tar-file-contents-without-untarring-it-in-python-script) . but in my case code doesn't work. the code is as follows :

```
import tarfile
import numpy as np 

tar = tarfile.open("filename.tar.gz", "r:gz")
for member in tar.getmembers():
     f=tar.extractfile(member)
     content = f.read()
     Data = np.loadtxt(content)
```

the error is as follows :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dataExtPlot.py", line 21, in <module>
    content = f.read()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

also, Is there any other method to do this task ?

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/q/33113600/1240268

Comment: *If member is none of the above, None is returned.*, the member is not a file or link.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) tell us that *None* is returned by *extractfile()* if the member is a not a regular file or link.

One possible solution is to skip over the *None* results:

```
tar = tarfile.open("filename.tar.gz", "r:gz")
for member in tar.getmembers():
     f = tar.extractfile(member)
     if f is not None:
         content = f.read()
```

Comment: Don't forget to `tar.close()` after you're done. Or better yet, use it as `with tarfile.open(...): ...`

Answer (score 6):

[`tarfile.extractfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractfile) can return `None` if the member is neither a file nor a link. For example your tar archive might contain directories or device files. To fix:

```
import tarfile
import numpy as np 

tar = tarfile.open("filename.tar.gz", "r:gz")
for member in tar.getmembers():
     f = tar.extractfile(member)
     if f:
         content = f.read()
         Data = np.loadtxt(content)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this one

```
t = tarfile.open("filename.gz", "r")
for filename in t.getnames():
    try:
        f = t.extractfile(filename)
        Data = f.read()
        print filename, ':', Data
    except :
        print 'ERROR: Did not find %s in tar archive' % filename
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. You are reading twice though - once in setting the "data" variable and the next time in printing. Can you change your code to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "read" the content of some special files such as links yet tar supports them and tarfile will extract them alright. When `tarfile` extracts them, it does not return a file-like object but None. And you get an error because your tarball contains such a special file.

One approach is to determine the type of an entry in a tarball you are processing ahead of extracting it: with this information at hand you can decide whether or not you can "read" the file. You can achieve this by calling `tarfile.getmembers()` returns `tarfile.TarInfo`s that contain detailed information about the type of file contained in the tarball.

The `tarfile.TarInfo` class has all the attributes and methods you need to determine the type of tar member such as `isfile()` or `isdir()` or `tinfo.islnk()` or `tinfo.issym()` and then accordingly decide what do to with each member (extract or not, etc).

For instance I use these to test the type of file in [this patched tarfile](https://github.com/nexB/scancode-toolkit/blob/68474f46e6bd125a6b4ee441ce760c6929e80482/src/extractcode/tar.py#L130) to skip extracting special files and process links in a special way:

```
for tinfo in tar.getmembers():
    is_special = not (tinfo.isfile() or tinfo.isdir()
                      or tinfo.islnk() or tinfo.issym())
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**My needs:**

1. Python3.
2. My tar.gz file consists of multiple `utf-8` text files and dir.
3. Need to read text lines from all files.

**Problems:**

1. The tar object returned by tar.getmembers() maybe `None`.
2. The content `extractfile(fname)` returns is a bytes str (e.g. b'Hello\t\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd').  Unicode char doesn't display correctly.

**Solutions:**

1. Check the type of tar object first. I reference the example in [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) of tarfile lib. (Search "How to read a gzip compressed tar archive and display some member information")
2. Decode from byte str to normal str. ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) - most voted answer)

**Code:**

```
with tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", "r:gz") as tar:
for tarinfo in tar:
    logger.info(f"{tarinfo.name} is {tarinfo.size} bytes in size and is: ")
    if tarinfo.isreg():
        logger.info(f"Is regular file: {tarinfo.name}")
        f = tar.extractfile(tarinfo.name)  
        # To get the str instead of bytes str
        # Decode with proper coding, e.g. utf-8
        content = f.read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        # Split the long str into lines
        # Specify your line-sep: e.g. \n
        lines = content.split('\n')
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            print(f"[{i}]: {line}\n")
    elif tarinfo.isdir():
        logger.info(f"Is dir: {tarinfo.name}")
    else:
        logger.info(f"Is something else: {tarinfo.name}.")
```

Comment: Use `content = codecs.getreader("utf-8")(f)` to convert the bytestream to stringstream! Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34511829/8567701

Answer (score 0):

Just to help people, I saw that conversion to text didn't work for me with the previous solutions so here is a solution to read files tar.gz into text that you can process into python:

```
tar = tarfile.open(tar_archive, 'r:gz')
files = tar.getmembers()
seqs_file = tar.extractfile(files[0])
seqs_file = gzip.open(seqs_file, 'rt')
content = seqs_file.readlines()
```

I think that if you have more files you can loop and open them one by one with gzip.open but I didn't test. I hope that this solution can be useful for other people.

Comment: Your solution assumes that all files in the archive are text files, and are compressed with gzip. In reality there maybe other types of files and folders also so make sure to modify the code to deal with these other possible use cases.

Answer (score -1):

In Jupyter notebook you can do like below

```
!wget -c http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/20news-bydate.tar.gz -O - | tar -xz
```